# Extracting values from JSON column using KQL (Azure Data Explorer)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Can you please tell me how to extract values of **category**, **enabled** and **categoryGroup** from the below JSON column in KQL(Azure Data Explorer).

Below JSON value is exactly what I see in the column called "**Logs**". I see that the Column **Logs** is defined as ***string* datatype** in table

```
AzLogsCoverage 
| extend Logs = case(isnull(Logs) or isempty(Logs), 'N/A', Logs)
| where Logs <> 'N/A'
| project Logs
| extend LogsCategory = parse_json(Logs).category
```

```html
[
  {
    "category": "Administrative",
    "enabled": true,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Security",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "ServiceHealth",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Alert",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Recommendation",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Policy",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Autoscale",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "ResourceHealth",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the input is of type `string`, you first need to invoke [`parse_json()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) on it, to make it of type [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic).

Then, you can use [`mv-expand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator)/[`mv-apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) to expand elements in the array, and then you can explicitly project properties of interest for each element.

for example:

````
print input = ```[
  {
    "category": "Administrative",
    "enabled": true,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Security",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "ServiceHealth",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Alert",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Recommendation",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Policy",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "Autoscale",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  },
  {
    "category": "ResourceHealth",
    "enabled": false,
    "categoryGroup": null
  }
]```
| extend d = parse_json(input)
| mv-apply d on (
    project Category = tostring(d.category),
            Enabled = tobool(d.enabled),
            CategoryGroup = tostring(d.categoryGroup)
)
| project-away input
````

| Category | Enabled | CategoryGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Administrative | True |  |
| Security | False |  |
| ServiceHealth | False |  |
| Alert | False |  |
| Recommendation | False |  |
| Policy | False |  |
| Autoscale | False |  |
| ResourceHealth | False |  |

Answer (score 0):

```html
AzLogsCoverage
| extend Logs = case(isnull(Logs) or isempty(Logs), 'N/A', Logs)
| extend Metrics = case(isnull(Metrics) or isempty(Metrics), 'N/A', Metrics)
| where Logs <> 'N/A'
| extend LogsDynamic = todynamic(Logs)
| extend MetricsDynamics = todynamic(Metrics)
| mv-expand LogsDynamic, MetricsDynamics
| project SubscriptionId, ResourceId, ResourceName, ResourceType, DiagnosticSettingStatus, DiagnosticSettingId, DiagnosticSettingName, DiagnosticSettingType, LAworkspaceId, LAworkspaceRetentionPeriod,   
LogsDynamic.category,LogsDynamic.enabled,LogsDynamic.categoryGroup, MetricsDynamics.category, MetricsDynamics.categoryGroup, MetricsDynamics.enabled, MetricsDynamics.retentionPolicy.enabled , MetricsDynamics.retentionPolicy.days
```